# To what does the following regular expression match?

Tags: regex

```
    ([^\s]+(?=\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))\.\2)
```

and this one:

```
    ([^\s]+(?=\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))\.\1)
```

and how does it match it? I'm pretty sure the starting part strips off the white spaces..or does it?

Thanks.

Comment: Note: a regular expression doesn't *do* anything, it just *matches* a string. You need to use some other language feature (like a `replace` method) to *do* something with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two are *awful* regexes. Where did you find them?

First, instead of `[^\s]+`, you can simply write `\S+` (= one or more non-whitespace characters.).

The second part `(?=\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))` looks ahead in the string to make sure that the following part of the string is a dot, followed by one of the listed graphics filename extensions.

Then, `\.\2` matches exactly that same text, making the previous lookahead assertion completely pointless. `\2` refers to the content of the second pair of capturing parentheses (which are those around `jpg|jpeg|png|gif`).

So the first regex can be rewritten as

```
\S+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)
```

The second one can never match (and will cause most, if not all, compilers to cough and die) because `\1` refers to the contents of the first set of parentheses which (completely uselessly) surround the entire regex. And of course, you can't include the entire match as a part of itself.

Comment: Good! Can be even more compact with: `\S+\.(jpe*g|png|gif)`

Comment: Just want you guys to know about this service: http://regex101.com/r/tM1aO0
Helps out when you want to explain a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks!    
the second regex was my own abominable invention for my own curiosity.
The first one I found online: [Dave's Cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: @Lindrian the link is very helpful! btw I also found www.regexpal.com which is also a very good aid.

Answer (score 3):

- `[^\s]+` - Matches 1 or more non-whitespace characters;
- `(?=\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)` - Zero-width (meaning it doesn't consume input) positive lookahead which *asserts* that following the above expression, you have a dot (`\.`), followed by one those four image extensions;
- `\.\2` - Matches a dot, followed by the second captured group, which is `(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)`.

In sum, `([^\s]+(?=\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))\.\2)`, matches 1 one or more non-whitespace characters (presumably a filename), followed by one of the following extensions: `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, or `.gif`.

The second one is basically the same, but since `\1` refers to the entire captured text, it will never match anything.